# Why won't Firefox display this redirect?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firefox-extensions, http, firebug

If I visit http://www.endsleigh.co.uk/Pages/Endsleigh-App.aspx then the request completes with a URL of https://www.endsleigh.co.uk/personal/

When this kind of thing has happened before with other sites, I've seen 3xx responses in Firebug, followed by the request to the second URL. But this time I don't see that, and Firefox's Live HTTP headers add-on doesn't show this either. It's as if I'd never typed in the first URL.

Then I tried it in Chrome, and saw a 301 redirect. Why would this be shown in Chrome but not in Firefox's native tools or headers add-on or indeed in Firebug?

Comment: I just tried it on chrome and firefox, but on both browsers, I get redirected immediately without seeing any 301 redirect. Maybe it is the speed of the connection, you see it on Firefox when the network is slower?

Comment: It could be because the 301 redirect is cached by Firefox. You could try clearing the **Cache** via **History** (Alt + S) > **Clear Recent History** with an appropriate **Time range to clear**. Alternatively, **Forget About This Site** via the History library. [Clearing cache/history](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/remove-recent-browsing-search-and-download-history)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to explain why firebug would not show the header. I would clear the cache, make sure [accessibility.blockautorefresh](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Accessibility.blockautorefresh)=true, and lastly use the [NoRedirect addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noredirect/).
You can then add two custom rules, leaving unchecked all three checkboxes

```
http://*.*
https://*.*
```

or perhaps even one regex rule as in this image:

[image]

I would hope after these 3 changes, that firebug would finally record the sent header.

Comment: Clearing the cache did it